# Unable to install or remove package

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

This specific message is displayed in the terminal

```
$ sudo apt-get remove bio-linux-cdbfasta
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bio-linux-cdbfasta
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 311 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 230300 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing bio-linux-cdbfasta (1:20100722bl-3) ...
Finished removing Bio-Linux package: bio-linux-cdbfasta
/var/lib/dpkg/info/bio-linux-cdbfasta.postrm: 3: /var/lib/dpkg/info/bio-linux-
cdbfasta.postrm: /usr/bin/update-menus: not found
dpkg: error processing package bio-linux-cdbfasta (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 bio-linux-cdbfasta
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The post-removal script of `bio-linux-cdbfasta` requires a program `/usr/bin/update-menus`, which is missing in your setup. Please re-install its package `menu`. Unfortunately, you cannot just use

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall menu
```

because `apt-get` will first try to remove any half-removed packages, which currently fails. Therefore you will need to manually download (or find it in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`) and install it:

```
apt-get download menu
sudo dpkg -i menu_*.deb
```

Afterwards, you should be able to uninstall `bio-linux-cdbfasta` normally.

Comment: Not working...above error is still repeated..unable to install package 'menu'

Comment: Can you please reproduce the exact error message, that you get when trying to re-install `menu`? It looks like there's a bunch of other broken stuff.

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  menu-l10n
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  bio-linux-cdbfasta
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  menu
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 455 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,490 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe menu amd64 2.1.46ubuntu1 [455 kB]
Fetched 455 kB in 8s (51.4 kB/s)

Comment: after this, the error message is the same as the above error message

Comment: I get the same error message everytime I try to install or remove any package. Even after using `sudo apt-get update`

Comment: Alright, I understand the issue (or at least I think so). See the update to my answer.

Comment: As you're a reputation 1 user: if this answers your question, don't forget to click the grey ☑ under the "0" at the left of this text to [accept it](/help/someone-answers), which means "yes, this answer is valid"!